# Tablenotes breaks off

Tags: tablenotes

I really do not know why the sentence is not just continued and it simply breaks off in any graphic I have in the text. Do you know how can avoid this? I circled it red.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt}
\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[figure]{skip=3pt}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\onehalfspacing
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics Graphically} \vspace{0.3cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm,height=28cm,keepaspectratio]{Figure2}
\begin{tablenotes} 

\item \footnotesize Source: based on Gonzalez and Ortega (2013).
\end{tablenotes} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code complete. Adding `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document} ... \end{document}`  your code works for me. Maybe you have some definition about note width.

Comment: You mean like above now?

Comment: Your preamble is a bit messy. For example you loaded `caption` three times, whereas only one is needed. But even making it compilable, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should put this preamble in your question.. That said, the height of the figure should be **28**cm? Which paper format do you use?

Comment: The publishers I've dealt with asked for figure source information be added to the caption instead of added at the bottom like this.

Answer (score 2):

The `tablenotes` environment has to be inserted in `threeparttable`. I suggest  using the `copyrightbox` package instead. I took the opportunity to simplify your code (needless to load threeparttable if you load threeparttablex, &c.).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt}\captionsetup[figure]{skip=3pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe} \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{10pt}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics Graphically} \vspace{0.3cm}
\centering
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=13cm, height=8cm, keepaspectratio]{Figure2}}
{Source: based on Gonzalez and Ortega (2013). Also based on Ortega and Gonzalez (2014). }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]